# Extern Declaration in Dynamic Library in LINUX

Tags: c++, linux, extern

I have a c++ dynamic library, which I want to run on linux.
in this library I have to declare a global variable which I want to use in 2 places.
so in one place I declared:

```
FILE *gFile;
```

then in the other place I declared it:

```
extern FILE *gFile;
```

till here all is OK.

I just want to ask regarding the application which will link to this dynamic library:
is there any problem that this application will declare THE SAME declaration of:

```
FILE *gFile;
```

will it have a conflict?

for STATIC library - I know that yes, for DYNAMIC library in linux - I don't know the answer...

Comment: Read [Drepper's how to write shared library](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Comment: `for DYNAMIC library in linux - I don't know the answer.` Why not write your own shared library in order to test check this question? Also you can use `LD_DEBUG=all` in order to inspect how your application is lunached.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch lol, nice RTFM :)